# How to deploy portlets to Liferay?

Tags: java, glassfish, portlet, liferay

I have faced problems in trying to install new portlets to Liferay running on Glassfish domain. I figured out the flow very lately and want to share it with others also. So, please read the answer and hope this helps someone :)

(Pre requisites for the problem is that I knew that adding projects running on **Glassfish** is done with a autodeploy folder, but making them visible on **Liferay** was another story.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, you make first a .war file let's say a portlet of name your_file.war. You wanna have it running on a glassfish domain under Liferay portal.

Steps to success:

1) Navigate to `Control Panel -> Plugins Installation on Liferay`
2) hit `Install new portlets` 
3) hit `Configuration`
4) Fill in to `Deploy Directory` a new place for deployment let's say **[your domain]/autodeploy2**
5) Check that in the next line target is **[your domain]/autodeploy** (it is the Glassfish default deployment directory)
6) hit `save`

Now deployment will be done by copy pasting files to that new directory **[your domain]/autodeploy2**. The rest of it is handled automatically. Setting takes action imediatedly.

Done with deployment: Make a victory jig and enjoy :)

..you stop dancing and face a bug. You want a new revision to be deployed.. In this case, continue reading.

So, you have built your war again and want to re-deploy. Do the following:

1) undeploy old stuff from **(your domain)/autodeploy** folder by deleting the war file. Don't delete any other file.

2) result is that your_file.war_UnDeployed file will appear.

3) deploy new file by copying the newly built war in **(your domain)/autodeploy2** folder.

4) result is that your_file.war_deployed will appear in **(your domain)/autodeploy** folder.

Make a dance again :)

Comment: I have found out that restarting server after deployment is mandatory. Almost always the hot deploy (deployment when server is on) needs a restart because of internal errors occurring during the deploy. Those problems don't have effect after fresh startup and don't affect to the actual deployment. Hot deployment just messes the already running processes.

Comment: You'll know that your war file is deployed when in autodeploy folder there appear two files: your_war.war and your_war.war_deployed. yours_war.war_deployFailed indicates a failure. In that case delete the war file and try all this again. Good tip is to try to copy the file after stopping server and starting then server again. That helps sometimes.

Comment: Liferay Menu `Plugins Installation` -> `Install Portlets` -> `Upload` works also like charm. Then no special directory is needed.

Comment: This mentioned folder is equal to `{LIFERAY_HOME}/deploy` and mostly it is only needed if you have problems with the original one.

Comment: You're my hero man, I struggled with this crap for days! And your tip worked first time. Thank you so so much.

Comment: I have installed a portlet as described by you. How can I view my portlet now?.

Comment: Log in to the portal and you find portlet at Add Application menu.

Comment: In Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.2 CE (Paton / Build 6102 / August 2, 2013) when clicking on "Install More Portlets" it redirects to the marketplace login :(

Comment: When I do this in a cluster, it only installs the portlet on one server. How do I get it to install on both servers in the cluster?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920725/liferay-cluster may this help? I have no other knowledge of cluster&liferay than what google tells.. That was what liferay + cluster told.

Answer (score 1):

There is several methods to deploy plugins (portlets, hooks, filters...) into your Liferay Portal.

If you're using Administration you can do it as Mico descripted. but if you're using Maven, Gradle, Ant, Ivi... you can configure their deployment descriptors and redirect their outputs (that are the wars) to the hotdeploy server folder (If you're using Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish...).

This approach is quite better because you can create backup webapp folder and restore it whenever you want easily.

Answer (score 0):

Below are not for Glassfish but common startup steps:

To install a portlet in lliferay portal

•   first install liferay portal from below link 
http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/wiki//wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial

```
this requires installation of
    liferay ide
    liferay portal bundled with tomcat
    add this tomcat as run server time and start it, it will start liferay portal
```

•   create a portlet application

•   open liferay at localhost:8080 and goto Admin -> control panel

•   goto   **Plugins Configuration**

•   goto Intall tab and give location of war file (some logging error might come 
at tomcat console, ignore it)

•   again goto home page at localhost:8080 and click **+** button

•   go at the bottom in the list and u will find ur portlet

•   click add button present at the right side of it and ur portlet would be added to the page.

Modifying code of portel requires to uninstall and install again the portlet from war file.
All existing added portlets would also be modified.