# Liferay on GlassFish: deployment fails

Tags: deployment, glassfish, liferay

Could anybody give a short-list what to do when deployment to Liferay (with Glassfish) fails? For me it is taking extensively time for getting to know new ways that the process can fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy a portlet to Glassfish and then try to see it in Liferay and you DO NOT see anything, check:
- Is the deploy failed?
- Is there a restart made before you go to see results?
- Does the server give you any errors on log?
- If deployment does not work one way, try another. You can use Liferay menu `Plugins Installation`-> `Upload File` or try the method on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260119/how-to-deploy-portlets-to-liferay)